# Get NodeSet Size in XML::XPath

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a XML i want to get the size of node set in the XML.

**XML**

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>data</c>
    <c>data</c>
    <c>data</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want to get the count **c** in the **b** tag.

```
my $obj = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);
print size(($obj->find('/a/b'));
```

I am not able to get the count of c in this XML

Comment: Note that XML::XPath is incomplete and hopelessly outdated. Try XML::LibXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size` is a method, not a function. Also, your XPath expression matches the `b` node, not its children.

The following works:

```
my $cs = $obj->find('/a/b/c');
print $cs->size, "\n";
```

Or, shorter, without the intermediate variable:

```
print $obj->find('/a/b/c')->size, "\n";
```